# Dedekind psi function

Tags: number-theory

How are you supposed to compute the Dedekind psi function?? Can someone give me an expansion that will explain how it works?

I have already tried the wikipedia article on it, but I don't see what the p|n means below the product sign. I don't get the same results as those in the series of the first numbers of the function.

Answer (score 2):

That use of "$p | n$" means "for each prime, $p$, dividing $n$".

From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_psi_function), we have the formula $$  
\psi(n) = n \prod_{p|n}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)  \text{.}  $$

Suppose we want $\psi(6)$.  The only primes dividing $6$ are $2$ and $3$.  So $$  \psi(6) = 6\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right) = 6 \cdot\frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{3} = 12  \text{.}$$

Note that the [MathWorld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DedekindFunction.html) has examples for the first several values, showing the same techniques as above.

In the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, this is [A001615](http://oeis.org/A001615).

Let's do a less straightforward example to see all of what's going on.  \begin{align}
\psi(10!) &= \psi(10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1)  \\
    &= \psi\left((2 \cdot 5) \cdot 3^2 \cdot 2^3 \cdot 7 \cdot (2 \cdot 3) \cdot 5 \cdot 2^2 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \right)  \\
    &= \psi(2^8 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7)  \\
    &= (10!) \left(1+ \frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1+ \frac{1}{3}\right)\left(1+ \frac{1}{5}\right)\left(1+ \frac{1}{7}\right)  \\
    &= (2^8 \cdot 3^4 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7) \cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{3} \cdot \frac{6}{5} \cdot \frac{8}{7}  \\
    &= (2^7 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5) \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdot 8  \\
    &= 2^{13} \cdot 3^5 \cdot 5  \\
    &= 9\,953\,280  \text{.}
\end{align}

Comment: So if it says n>1 below e.g. a sigma,

Comment: @user504882 : That uses the convention that $n$ is an integer together with the explicit "$n > 1$" to indicate that the summand is evaluated at $n=2$, $n=3$, $n=4$, ...